# XI52 "any-to-any" transformations

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a virtual XI52 gateway with firmware version of IDG.7.5.1.0.  I would like to test transforming from one type to another (json to xml or vice versa is fine) and also (if possible) interacting with the transformation via SOMA in the XML management interface.  I've been looking around all day for a simple example of how to do a transformation and haven't found one.

Any examples on how to do this?  Even if there's a solid/understandable doc about how to set this up would be great.

Comment: you might look around e.g. in [Hermann SW's blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW?lang=en) or around other pertinent IBM pages... good luck

Comment: @StefanHegny Thanks for the recommendation to look at Hermann's blog - I've read some of his posts and found them helpful.

Comment: SOMA (or RMI) is for configuration. Why would you use that for transformation?

Comment: Also, for transformation, look into GatewayScript or WebSphere Transformation Extender.

Comment: @Anders Through SOMA, can I retrieve information about transformations?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean/need... Through SOMA you can export/import configuration but you don't get any specification like WSDL or Swagger if that is what you seek. That you would add to the service.